# How to Store File Upload in MINIO using Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-9, laravel-livewire, minio

This method I use for upload file in MINIO is functioning in other Laravel project (using Laravel 7.0), but right now I'm working for Livewire Project (using Laravel 9.0) and the method is not working. This is the code:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use App\Models\AlmProofs;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class DocumentationProof extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $photo;
    public $modalplugin = false;

    protected $rules = [
        'photo' => 'mimes:png,pdf',
    ];


    public function submitForm()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $files = $this->photo;
        $originalName = $files->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = time() . '-' . $originalName;

        $details = AlmProofs::where('users_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

        if (isset($details)) {
            $details->delete();
        }

        AlmProofs::create([
            'users_id'  => Auth::user()->id,
            'ori_name'  => $originalName,
            'file_name' => $fileName,
            'web_path'  => "alumni/".$fileName,
        ]);

        $this->photo->storeAs('proof', $fileName);
        Storage::disk('minio')->put("/alumni/".$fileName, file_get_contents($files));

        $this->modalplugin = true;
    }

    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.documentation-proof')->layout('layouts.management');
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
<x-slot name="header">
    {{ __('Documentation Proof') }}
</x-slot>
<div x-data="employment"
    class="min-h-full overflow-hidden bg-white p-6 shadow-xl md:rounded-lg"
    x-init="$watch('modalAlpine', function(value, oldValue) {
        modal_checkbox.checked = value;
        if (modal_checkbox.checked) {
            bgOverlay.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            bgOverlay.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    })">
    <h1 class="font-bold">Documentation Proof</h1>

    <div
        class="mx-auto max-w-md overflow-hidden rounded-xl bg-white px-6 py-4 shadow-md md:max-w-4xl">
        <div class="md:flex">
            <div class="mt-6 w-full overflow-hidden">
                <x-jet-validation-errors class="mb-4" />

                <form wire:submit.prevent="submitForm">
                    <div>
                        @if (session()->has('message'))
                            <div
                                class="alert alert-success mb-4 text-orange-500">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                {{ session('message') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:space-x-3">
                        <div class="w-full">
                            <label for="remark"
                                class="font-small text-sm text-gray-700">
                                Please upload one file only - ie.Certificate of Completion
                            </label>

                            <input type="file" wire:model="photo"
                                class="block w-full">

                            <label for="remark"
                                class="font-small mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 text-sm text-red-500">
                                File format: .png/.pdf only</label>

                            {{-- {{ $proofFile }} --}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-4 flex justify-end space-x-3">
                        <div class="text-sm text-red-600">
                            {{ __('Please click save button after every update') }}

                        </div>
                        <div class=""> <button
                                class="rounded-md border border-transparent bg-orange-400 px-4 py-2 text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-widest text-white transition hover:bg-orange-600 focus:border-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-gray-300 active:bg-gray-900 disabled:opacity-25">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <input id="modal-checkbox" type="checkbox"
                    class="peer hidden" />
                <div
                    class="top-50 sm: absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 z-10 w-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 scale-0 transform px-2 opacity-0 transition-all duration-300 peer-checked:scale-100 peer-checked:opacity-100 md:w-1/4">
                    <livewire:intec-modal-plugin>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const modal_checkbox = document.getElementById('modal-checkbox');
        const bgOverlay = document.getElementById('bg-overlay');

        document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
            Alpine.data('employment', () => ({
                modalAlpine: @entangle('modalplugin'),

                toggle() {
                    modal_checkbox.checked = !
                        modal_checkbox.checked;
                    this.modalAlpine = modal_checkbox.checked;

                    if (modal_checkbox.checked) {
                        bgOverlay.classList.remove('hidden');
                    } else {
                        bgOverlay.classList.add('hidden');
                    }
                },
            }))
        })
    </script>
</div>
```

filesystems.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),
 
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'minio' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'endpoint' => env('MINIO_ENDPOINT', '(url)'),
            'url' => env('MINIO_ENDPOINT', '(url)'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'visibility' => 'public'
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],
];
```

I have tried upload the file, it saved in storage/app/proof but not in MINIO. This is the error statement displayed:

> file_get_contents(C:\Users\akobo\AppData\Local\Temp\phpFA54.tmp): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I tried searching for this error but nothing worked.